# Shared Documents on sub-site

Tags: sharepoint-2007, document

I would like to show the Shared Documents on a sub-site of a main site.

I have a main site with multiple sub-sites, and I would like to show the Shared Documents library of the Main site on every sub-site below it on their 'home' pages.

I have tried adding Shared Documents as a web part, but of course that only shows the Shared Documents of that particular sub-site.

How is this accomplished using Sharepoint 2007?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this using only the UI with Windows Sharepoint Services.

You could try adding a data view web part with Sharepoint Designer.